# gradle is throwing me this error "Running Gradle build - failed!" when i run "npx cap run android"

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

i want to use a software called "db app maker" and it is used to make mobile app with databases.
so i stared installing it's dependency like java, node, ionic, cordova, "gradle"  [as per the instructions given in the sitext](https://www.hkvstore.com/doc/hh_start.htm) after installing everything and adding everything in the environmental variables i am facing this error saying "running gradle build - failed"

My android studio installed sdks

[image]

this is my error

```
D:\myApp>npx cap run android --scan
√ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 2.19s
√ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.88ms
[info] Inlining sourcemaps
√ copy android in 2.33s
√ Updating Android plugins in 6.68ms
[info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for android:
       @capacitor/app@5.0.3
       @capacitor/haptics@5.0.4
       @capacitor/keyboard@5.0.4
       @capacitor/status-bar@5.0.4
√ update android in 117.58ms
× Running Gradle build - failed!
[error]
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
        > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0.
        Required by:
        project :
        > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a
        library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared
        externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.2' but:
        - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar,
        and its dependencies declared externally:
        - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11
        and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
        - Other compatible attribute:
        - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
        - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during
        runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
        - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
        - Other compatible attributes:
        - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
        - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
        - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
        - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library for use during
        runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
        - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a
        component, compatible with Java 8
        - Other compatible attribute:
        - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
        - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during
        runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
        - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
        - Other compatible attributes:
        - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
        - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
        - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')

        * Try:
        > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
        > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        > Run with --scan to get full insights.

        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

        BUILD FAILED in 1s
```